# ClientDataSet's Savetostream with dfxml parameter throws access violation

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Opened clientDataSet and getting:

```
cds.XMLData
```

or

```
st_pom := TMemoryStream.Create;
cds.SaveToStream(st_pom, dfXML );
```

results in AV. Has anyone encountered such behaviour?

I CAN ADD that cds has two fields: numeric and NVarchar(max) ..
It seems as the second field is the problem ...

Here are the last traces after which AV occurs

```
'{ Original Exception - Access violation at address 4DB10D54. Write of address 05017000 }'
(0002FD54) [4DB10D54]'#$D#$A'(000B2CB3) [004B3CB3] DBClient.TCustomClientDataSet.SaveDataPacket (Line 1500, "DBClient.pas" + 5) + $15'
(000B4385) [004B5385] DBClient.TCustomClientDataSet.WriteDataPacket (Line 2119, "DBClient.pas" + 5) + $6'
(000B457B) [004B557B] DBClient.TCustomClientDataSet.SaveToStream (Line 2186, "DBClient.pas" + 1) + $C'
```

Comment: It looks like cds is either **nil** or it is accidentally destroyed already.

Comment: No, everything is ok. For smaller returned dataset it works ok.

Comment: Any strange characters (that XML might not like) in your dataset?  What if you iterate through the dataset - does the iteration complete?

Comment: Iterating to the and of dataset doesn't raise error. Also SavingToStream without dfxml parameter is also ok. That nvarchar(max) field can contain even 65000 signs ...

Comment: "Throws access violation" is meaningless unless you provide the **exact error message**, including any memory addresses.

Comment: Check `Use Debug DCUs" options, install stack tracers like JCL Debug Dialog or madExcept or Eureka or whatever, then see the exact place of the error.

Then give the exact error message.

Comment: According to the top two lines of the stack trace, the problem is related to `#$D#$A` (at address `4DB10D45`, which appears in both lines. You're going to need to use debug .dcus, set a breakpoint at the start of `TCustomClientDataSet.SetDataPacket`, and see exactly what's triggering the exception. We don't have the data (I don't even have D7 installed on most machines any more).